# How can i print the current date and time to an external text document?

Tags: java, file, date, time, printing

I can get the date and time to print to the screen, but i cannot get it to print to the specified text document:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class GetCurrentTimeStamp 
{
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream ("transaction-list.txt");  
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();

    System.out.print(date);
    output.close(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating `output` and not even using it before you close it? What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
output.print(date);
```

instead of `System.out.print(date);`

Answer (score 1):

System.out.print() writes to the system console, not the file.  You're creating a PrintStream but then writing the date output to the console.  Try this:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("transaction-list.txt");
Date date = new Date();
ps.println(date.toString());
ps.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("transaction-list.txt", true))) // take away true, if you dont want it to append.
output.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Modern way to get current time in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

```
String output = Instant.now().toString(); // In UTC, standard format.
```

or, zoned:

```
String output = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toString();
```

---

## java.time

The other answers are correct, but use of `java.util.Date` is outmoded now by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

The standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) may be all you need. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
String output = Instant.now().toString();  // 2011-12-03T10:15:30.728Z
```

Generally best to perform business logic and data exchange in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). But if expected by your user or data sink, you can can apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3-4 abbreviations like `EST` or `IST` seen in the media.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneID );
String output = zdt.toString();  // 2011-12-03T05:15:30.728-05:00[America/Montreal]
```

You can skip the `Instant` object as a shortcut.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

Toss it all together for a one-liner.

```
String output = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toString();
```

For other formats, search Stack Overflow for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).